# Enable SSL for Kafka Clients

Tags: apache-kafka

Kafka allows clients to connect over SSL. By default SSL is disabled, but I have  enabled by referring the below link.
http://docs.confluent.io/2.0.0/kafka/ssl.html

After all configuration was done  ,Producer/Consumer unable to produce/consume the message.

```
    [2016-02-29 09:20:49,189] ERROR Error when sending message to topic ssltopic with key: null, value: 2 bytes with error: Failed to update metadata after 60000 ms. (org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.ErrorLoggingCallback)
sas
[2016-02-29 09:21:16,031] WARN Failed to send SSL Close message  (org.apache.kafka.common.network.SslTransportLayer)
java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer
```

Answer (score 7):

The above answer by supermonk clarifies most of the places to check. I faced the similar problem as the OP and the mistake was not in the broker configuration but the client side configuration. 
In the official [documentation](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation#security_configclients), although they implicitly mentioned to create the client.keystore as step 1, I missed signing the certificate with the CA as done for the server.keystore. This was causing the Kafka broker to refuse the connection from the clients (producer/consumer). 
Performing these two steps has eliminated the problem in my case.

```
keytool -keystore kafka.client.keystore.jks -alias localhost -certreq -file cert-file
openssl x509 -req -CA ca-cert -CAkey ca-key -in cert-file -out cert-signed -days $VALIDITY -CAcreateserial -passin pass:$PASSWORD

keytool -keystore kafka.client.keystore.jks -alias CARoot -import -file ca-cert
keytool -keystore kafka.client.keystore.jks -alias localhost -import -file cert-signed
```

This will sign the certificate using the CA-cert and add the CARoot as well as signed certificates to the client.keystore.

Reference: [Confluent blog on securing Apache Kafka](https://www.confluent.io/blog/apache-kafka-security-authorization-authentication-encryption/)

Comment: KAFKA-5401 was a duplicate of KAFKA-3702 and that issue is now resolved. If you're still experiencing this issue, it's likely that your cert isn't signed properly. Either way, please don't use self-signed certs and get a "real" certificate. :)

Answer (score 6):

Below are some of verification steps.Since the error log is not detailed, Could you try the below step to validate if the setup is good.

1. To verify if the server’s `keystore` and `truststore` are setup correctly you can run the following command:

   openssl s_client -debug -connect localhost:9093 -tls1 Note: TLSv1 should be listed under ssl.enabled.protocols.

In the output of this command you should see the server’s certificate:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
{variable sized random bytes} 
-----END CERTIFICATE----- 
subject=/C=US/ST=CA/L=Santa Clara/O=org/OU=org/CN=Joe Smith   issuer=/C=US/ST=CA/L=Santa Clara/O=org/OU=org/CN=kafka/emailAddress=test@test.com
```

If the certificate does not show up or if there are any other error messages then your `keystore` is not setup correctly.

2. Check the server.properties

   ```
   echo "############################# Security  #############################" >>server.properties
   echo "listeners=SSL://:9093" >>server.properties
   echo "security.inter.broker.protocol=SSL" >> server.properties
   echo "ssl.client.auth=required" >> server.properties
   echo "ssl.keystore.location=/home/vagrant/securityDemo/kafka.server.keystore.jks" >> server.properties
   echo "ssl.keystore.password=test1234" >> server.properties
   echo "ssl.key.password=test1234" >> server.properties
   echo "ssl.truststore.location=/home/vagrant/securityDemo/kafka.server.truststore.jks" >> server.properties
   echo "ssl.truststore.password=test1234" >> server.properties
   echo "ssl.enabled.protocols=TLSv1.2,TLSv1.1,TLSv1" >> server.properties
   echo "authorizer.class.name=kafka.security.auth.SimpleAclAuthorizer" >>, if acl enabled ** server.properties
   ```
3. Make sure you have only one CA root.

[Reference 1.](http://docs.confluent.io/2.0.0/kafka/ssl.html)   and [Reference 2.](https://github.com/Symantec/kafka-security-0.9)